# Angular/React - How can I achieve 100% width on an iPhone in landscape mode?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, angular, material-ui

I was testing my site on my iPhone and noticed that in landscape view that Safari adds a major gap to either side of the app. Does anyone know how to fix this? It happens in both Angular and React apps. You can see examples of both in the screenshots below.

I've tested this to the best of my capability and have not had any success. To recreate this issue for yourself, generate a new react or angular app and load it up on an iPhone in landscape mode. The screenshots are from a simulator but it happens on device as well.

[image: Clean angular app] [image: Clean React App]

EDIT: The source code is boilerplate generated by Angular and React respectively. Here's a copy of the React source:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen',
    'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue',
    sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: REDACTED
reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution! Adding `viewport-fit=cover` to the meta tag in the html header did the trick. Thanks to everyone that chimed in with an answer, y'all are great!

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 viewport-fit=cover" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide some Code to describe exactly issue is occurring?

May be you can try Media Query and define `orientation => landscape`

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) 
                    and (max-device-width: 640px) 
                    and (orientation: landscape) {
                         //enter code here...
                    }
```

And you can check there is `no Margin and Padding` in the outer wrapper or `Margin : auto`

I hope it may help you. All the best!!!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I added the source for the boilerplate react template that is pictured above. I think this has to do with apple's safe areas.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
in `index.css`:

```
html{
  margin:0,
  padding:0
}

body{
  margin:0,
  padding:0
}
```